# How to achieve Speech-to-text input in tvOS

Tags: speech-to-text, tvos

How to achieve Speech-to-text input in tvOS, like - have a mic Button and on Tapping a mic button and on speaking by the user, the audio should convert into text.

Tried to find related framework like Speech in ios but i didn't get for tvOS.